# Updated website through FTP but still showing old content

Tags: javascript, html, css, ftp

I am working at a project on my webhost. Until today everything went fine, but now I save the files, they update on the ftp but when I refresh the my webpage the old content shows up, not the updated one.

I checked the FTP, the files are updated with the new content and saved. I checked with the Chrome Dev Tools and I keep getting the old content from the files I work on.

I tried deleting the cache a few times but it only worked temporarily(once), and then again the content not updating.

I work with php, css and javascript files, all having the same problem.

What is wrong?

Comment: even when using different browser to view changes?

Comment: Yes, Chrome as well as Mozilla does the same.

Comment: Is it possible that something changed on the host, whereby now the web site is being served from a different location than the location that you are FTP'ing to?

Comment: I am actually using a CDN for my website, might that be the problem?

Comment: CTRL + F5 the page, what happens?

Comment: Same thing, the problem was from my CDN provider, they had issues. I'm now back to the normal webhost and nameservers and everything works flawless. I replied below the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Cloudflare automatically saves some files (i.e. Javascript's, CSS...). When you're in that kind of problems, in Cloudflare you should go to your page's settings and then "Cache Purge", you purge the cache and then it should work nice.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

It was because of a CDN I was using, called CloudFlare. I have no idea why, but it kept the old content instead of updating the new one.

Be careful when using CDN's.